# Hobspot webhook issue

Tags: node.js, hubspot

I have developed HubSpot integration using nodejs, I have set a webhook in hotspot as tutorial provided by HubSpot. Now the issue is: webhook is not firing from HubSpot to my server URL, if I test the webhook URL with POSTMan it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 issues that might be causing the problem:

- The workflow is not really active.
- The workflow is active, but the rules to trigger the workflow are not met.
- The workflow is active, but the webhook is not firing successfully. You can check the logs of the workflow by going into its "History" tab.
- The workflow is being triggered, but not immediately. This does happen frequently; we have seen times where the workflow takes hours to trigger.